# bxSlider and ajax asynchron loading doesn't work in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, bxslider

this Problem drives me crazy. I've a script like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if($('#articleslider').length) {

            var slider = $('#articleslider'),
                    articleslider = $('#articleslider').bxSlider({
                        speed: 800,
                        video: true,
                        useCSS: false,
                        easing: 'easeInOutQuart',
                        adaptiveHeight: true,
                        pager: false,
                        nextSelector: '#slider-next',
                        prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
                        nextText:'›',
                        prevText:'‹',
                        swipeThreshold: 100,
                        preventDefaultSwipeY: true
                    });

            var getImages = function() {

                $.ajax({
                  url: "/foo/",
                  //async: false,
                  dataType: "html"
                })

                .done(function(data) {
                    slider.html(data);
                    articleslider.reloadSlider();
                });
            }

            getImages();

        }
    });
```

> The Ajax Request is in function, because i want to use it in some other events.

In FF or Chrome it works as intended. IE(10) don't. I get the Pictures via Ajax, but the reloadSlider() or the bxSlider() doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem.

In my case, simulating the clicking via jQuery revealed the error pointing at the `easing: 'easeInOutQuart'` line being the culprit. So in your slider's case try this jQuery to click the next button in IE9's developer tools:

```
jQuery('#slider-next').click();
```

I got this error:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'easeInOutQuart'
```

I commented that line out and the sliding resumed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now, we use another method to integrate the bxSlider. But maybe it is helpful for some other people, which run into the same problem. Thank you.